# Video.js onclick events to expand screen to full screen mode and unmute

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, video.js, brightcove

I'm working with video.js in an Ionic Angular environment and I am having trouble setting an onclick event (on the video itself). I have tried several solutions such as:

```
$scope.videoClicked = function () {
      console.log('video clicked');
      promoPlayer.requestFullscreen();
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("click", event.clientX, event.clientY, promoPlayer.currentTime());
}
```

where the videoClicked method is attached to the  element with an ng-click event.

I've tried something like this:

```
$(promoPlayer).on("click", function (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

but I can't get the console.log event to even fire.

Any advice on how to even get the on click event to fire when the video is clicked? I would imagine the requestFullscreen method should really take care of the rest for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure of why you are using `video.js` versus HTML5's `<video>` tag. If you want to accomplish more complicated playback then you can explore [Videogular](http://www.videogular.com/), otherwise, you could try:

your **Template.html**

```
        <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
            <source src="{{trustSrc(video)}}">
        </video>
```

then in your **Controller.js**

```
    //return trusted external links
  $scope.trustSrc = function (src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  };
```

and remember to import `$sce` as explained [here](https://www.google.com.jm/search?q=sce%20angular1&rlz=1C5CHFA_enJM755JM755&oq=sce%20angular1&aqs=chrome..69i57.2642j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)